# Two DropDownLists in this same site

Tags: development, asp.net

I have got two DropDownLists. I want when I set in one value it should change in secound DropDownList the vales. Please Help.

Always the values should look like updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this by ASP.NET. Here is a code :)

```
        protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList3.SelectedIndex = (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex-1);
    }

    protected void DropDownList3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = (DropDownList3.SelectedIndex+1);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use jQuery for that..

```
      <input id='dd1' onchange="setval()" />

      <script type="text/javascript">
      Function setval(){
            $("#dd2").val( $("#dd1").val() );
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this functionality in SharePoint forms using the [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) open source library.

> The SPCascadeDropdowns function lets you set up cascading dropdowns on
>   SharePoint forms. What this means is that you can enforce hierarchical
>   relationships between column values.

Here's some documentation for it: [link](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns&referringTitle=Documentation)

---

If you just need an ASP.Net way of doing it, then you can do it by updating the datasource of `dropdown2` in the `dropdown1_OnSelectedIndexChanged` server method. Here's an in-depth example for this: [link](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Creating-Cascading-DropDownLists-in-ASP.Net.aspx)